# Max length of property text on objects in Forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge

In some Navisworks models the text in some of the object parameters are very long. It seems to be a max length of 999 characters when these models are translated to the LMV format.

Is this a limitation i Navisworks or in the translation? And is there any way for us to be able to handle longer texts?

Comment: I tried to input long string within Navisworks UI, adding custom property, it looks it also accepts max 999 chars only. And yes, since it is 999,  LMV format has only 999 chars. Could you share a demo that the source Navisworks has long string more than 999 chars?  I think it makes sense LMV has limit of string length, I can double ask engineer team, while I wanted to check the mismatch of translation.

Comment: I have sent a model in an e-mail to forge help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out with great help from Xiaodong that the text lengt linit is in Navisworks and not in the Forge viewer.